# Shadow map perspective aliasing

Tags: c++, opengl, shadow, shadow-mapping

It seems impossible to remove this sort of perspective aliasing when the surface is nearly parallel to the light direction.

[image]

I have tested several different shadow acne removing techniques:

- Constant bias doesn't work: Introduces peter panning on biases large enough to remove the issue
- Slope-scale bias doesn't work completely, only lessens the problem slightly
- Normal offset shadows don't work, and introduce extra shadow deformations
- glPolygonOffset doesn't work, and I suspect it's the same as slope-scale bias
- PCL just slightly antialiases the patterns, doesn't actually solve the problem. The amount of filtering required to kill the pattern would make giant blob shadows
- VSM doesn't do much, just changes the patterns slightly
- Increasing the shadow map resolution and pixel depth lessen the problem, but the resolution large enough to completely fix the issue would bring down frame rate considerably
- Expanding the near and far planes of the projection transform for the shadow map creation also doesn't do anything

From what it seems at looking at everything I can find at Google and my books, this is basically an unsolvable issue. I know there must be ways around it however, because even some indie games have perfect and smooth shadow map shadows.

Anybody willing to share this tightly kept secret?

Comment: `glPolygonOffset` actually ***is*** slope-scale bias. And expanding the near / far planes is actually the opposite of what you want, that will hurt the resolving ability of your depth buffer and lead to *more* aliasing. Have you considered Cascaded Shadow Maps? They work quite well at distributing shadow precision in a perspective projection.

Comment: That wouldn't really be a solution to the problem. Also, the demo from which I took that screenshot currently uses Cascaded Shadow Maps, and you can see from the image that it's still pretty bad at times

Comment: Why would it not be a solution? That stair-step comes from inadequately fitting the shadow map to the projection (light-space and view-space texel size). Anything that combats over/undersampling will generally help, but applying a bias to your depth does not actually fix issues associated with bad sample size. A bias is only effective in combatting issues associated with quantization (e.g. precision of depth buffer is insufficient to register a change in depth). Your problem is with the sample size and not the accuracy of the stored depth.

Comment: So correctly implemented CSM should be able to completely remove perspective aliasing? As I said, that demo I took the image from IS currently using CSM

Comment: No, nothing will *completely* remove this problem short of storing more information than a single sampled depth value per-texel. VSM tries to do that by storing the *variance* in depth; if nothing else that removes the need for a bias (see [figure 8-3](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch08.html) for an explanation). VSM can actually be combined with CSM, which will help with aliasing at both ends (CSM produces better sample fitting and VSM allows better filtering during reconstruction).

Comment: What books are you referring to in your question, by the way? [Real-Time Shadows](http://www.amazon.com/Real-Time-Shadows-Elmar-Eisemann/dp/1568814380) has a thorough discussion of all the major warping and partitioning strategies to help with perspective aliasing in *Chapter 4*.

Comment: I have the generic OpenGL bibles and 3D graphics books, didn't think of searching for a book specific on shadowing. I'll definitely take a look, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have already found an answer since the question is three years old, but I'd still want to say that artifacts on surfaces parallel to light direction must be fixed with normal offset. At least I just solved the same problem with that approach. It was

```
vec4 shadowPosition = lightMatrix * vec4(_position, 1.0);
float bias = 0.0002;
float visibility = (texture(shadow, shadowPosition.xy / 2. + .5).r - .5) * 2. < shadowPosition.z - bias ? 0.1: 1.0;
```

[image: rendering artifacts]

And now it is

```
float bias = 0.02;
vec4 shadowPosition = lightMatrix * vec4(_position + _normal * bias, 1.);
float visibility = (texture(shadow, shadowPosition.xy / 2. + .5).r - .5) * 2. < shadowPosition.z ? 0.1: 1.0;
```

[image: artifacts are gone]

Yes, the shadow's border is now jagged, but I'll hope some other techniques would help me to smooth it later.